# ag-grid with typescript 3.9 - getting build error

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

Compilation fails with set of errors like:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/ag-grid-community/src/ts/headerRendering/horizontalResizeService.ts:58:52 - error TS2551: Property 'msUserSelect' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclarati
on'. Did you mean 'userSelect'?

58         this.oldMsUserSelect = this.eGridDiv.style.msUserSelect;
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:3057:5
    3057     userSelect: string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~
    'userSelect' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that at the start of TS 3.9 [all properties of CSSStyleDeclaration like msUserSelect were "unprefixed"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/37616/files#diff-46fd87925e4552c166ec188712741c3fL3055).

My workaround is to "return" missed properties:

```
// remove this after ag-grid will get support of TS 3.9
declare global {
    interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
        msUserSelect: string;
        msOverflowStyle: string;
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(CSSStyleDeclaration, "msUserSelect", {
    get: function getter() {
        return this.userSelect;
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(CSSStyleDeclaration, "msOverflowStyle", {
    get: function getter() {
        return this.overflowStyle;
    }
});
```

I hope it helps to someone... :)